# Find total number of stackoverflow users by intepreting meaning of number in user profile URL

Tags: discussion

In my profile page, it shows top `0.59% this quarter` - how can I know how many users actually constitute this `0.59%`?

In other words how one can find out total number of users in StackOverflow?

I noticed that all user profile page URLs look like `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<six-digit-number>`.  So, I started entering six digit numbers to try to find out at which value it will give me `Page not found`.   At the time of writing this question, below URL gave error

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/900002/
```

whereas URL with one less number gave me a valid user page.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/900001/
```

Does these numbers mean user count?

Comment: Stack Overflow metrics: https://sostats.github.io/

Comment: Stack Overflow moderators: http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New users are given an incremental ID, but not all user accounts are kept. Sometimes users delete their account again, often moderators delete the account (because they were spamming, say), and inactive accounts (without a full registration and other activity) are removed periodically by the system.

Users 900002 and 900003 were removed because they were inactive, but there is a user 900004 in the system still.

Your top 0.59% percentage is applied against the number of people *that saw a reputation change this quarter*. You are ranked [number 1063](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2015-07-01/794242#794242) out of 179924 such accounts (just click on the last page in the batch navigator at the bottom). That's `(1063 / 179924) * 100` == `0.5908050065583246%`.

The site makes that calculation for each of the periods (week, month, quarter, year and overall), and displays only the highest ranking on your profile.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this post, the newest user has a 7 digit ID:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/5209820/
```

I found that by going to the Users page, clicking new users and then sorting by creation date.

---

A deleted page indicates that user has been removed from the system. If you increment your test to 900004, it shows there is another user.